# Updating table based on the value from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

So I have these two tables:

```
TEST_TABLE_A
------- ------ ------ --------    
 NAME    VAL1   VAL2   STATUS
------- ------ ------ --------
 HEAD1   100    200    ACTIVE
 HEAD2   300    400    ACTIVE
 HEAD3   500    600    ACTIVE
 HEAD4   700    800    ACTIVE


TEST_TABLE_B
------- ------ ------    
 NAME    VAL1   VAL2
------- ------ ------
 HEAD1   1      2
 HEAD2   3      4
 HEAD3   500    600
```

And I want to sync table a based on table b and the desired standing in table a should be like this

```
 NAME    VAL1   VAL2   STATUS
------- ------ ------ ----------
 HEAD1   100    200    INACTIVE
 HEAD1     1      2      ACTIVE
 HEAD2   300    400    INACTIVE
 HEAD2     3      4      ACTIVE
 HEAD3   500    600      ACTIVE
 HEAD4   700    800      ACTIVE
```

I dont know how to do it with my query please help me:

```
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE_A (NAME,VAL1,VAL2,STATUS)
SELECT NAME, VAL1, VAL2, 'ACTIVE' FROM TEST_TABLE_B
Where TEST_TABLE_A.NAME = TEST_TABLE_B.NAME
  AND TEST_TABLE_A.VAL1 != TEST_TABLE_B.VAL1
  AND TEST_TABLE_A.VAL2 != TEST_TABLE_B.VAL2
  AND TEST_TABLE_A.STATUS = 'ACTIVE';

UPDATE TEST_TABLE_A SET STATUS = 'INACTIVE'
Where TEST_TABLE_A.NAME = TEST_TABLE_B.NAME
  AND TEST_TABLE_A.VAL1 != TEST_TABLE_B.VAL1
  AND TEST_TABLE_A.VAL2 != TEST_TABLE_B.VAL2
  AND TEST_TABLE_A.STATUS = 'ACTIVE';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`SQL FIDDLE`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9b185/3)

First UPDATE status to inactive when name matches but values doesn't match
Insert new entries , i am using MERGE for this.

```
UPDATE TEST_TABLE_A A
SET A.STATUS ='INACTIVE'
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM TEST_TABLE_B B
    WHERE B."NAME" = A."NAME"
      AND B."VAL1" != A."VAL1" AND B."VAL2" != A."VAL2"
);

MERGE INTO TEST_TABLE_A D
USING ( SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE_B) S
ON ( D."NAME" = S."NAME" AND D."VAL1" = S."VAL1" AND D."VAL2"= S."VAL2")
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (D."NAME", D."VAL1",D."VAL2", D."STATUS")
values (S."NAME", S."VAL1",S."VAL2", 'ACTIVE');
```